# How to NOT count control characters in a text file

Tags: java, text, io, java.util.scanner, delimiter

I am having trouble understanding how to NOT count control characters in a text file. My program does everything but skip control characters `\n \r`:
contents of file: Ok upon further tries I am closer. If I change:

```
 while (input.hasNext()) { 
          String line = input.nextLine();
          lineCount++;
          wordCount += countWords(line);
          charcount += line.length(); 
 to
 while (input.hasNext()) {
          String line = input.next();
          lineCount++;
          wordCount += countWords(line);
          charCount += line.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "").length();
```

the chars are counted but it messes up the lines. If I add the input.nextLine it messes up the chars.
contents of text file:
cat
sad dog
dog wag

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Character_count {

 public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

     java.io.File file = new java.io.File("textFile.txt");

        // Create a Scanner for the file
        Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
        int charcount = 0;
        int wordCount = 0;
        int lineCount = 0;

        while (input.hasNext()) {
          String line = input.nextLine();
          lineCount++;
          wordCount += countWords(line);
          charcount += line.length();
        }


        System.out.println("The file " + file + " has ");
        System.out.println(charcount + " characters");
        System.out.println(wordCount + " words");
        System.out.println(lineCount + " lines");

        }

    private static int countWords(String s) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(s);
            int count = 0;

        while (input.hasNext()) {
            input.next(); 
        count++;
        }
        return count;

  }
}
```

Comment: For the character count try replacing the carriage returns and newlines with nothing in `line` before counting them. Something like `charcount += line.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "").length()`

Comment: this does not work for me

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that with your [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) by using the [`useDelimiter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter(java.lang.String)) method:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("textFile.txt"));
input.useDelimiter("\r\n");
```

And continue with your code as usual, should work.

Also (and **very important**) if you check `hasNext()` then use `next()`, and if you check `hasNextLine()` use `nextLine()`! Don't mix-and-match as it will cause (or already causing) issues down the line.

Comment: This does not work for me. It still counts the spaces. This is mentioned in my readings but very vague

Comment: Did you also apply the part after the "Also"  (use `hasNextLine()` instead of `hasNext()`?)

Comment: no dice. I had something like this before I asked the question but no matter what I did it just wouldn't work

Comment: Ahm, i'll try to think some more. Please post the content of your `File` inside your question too

Comment: Did you notice **any** difference of `count` before and after you used my delimiter? Or was it **exactly** the same?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105295/discussion-between-jake-and-idos).

Answer (score 1):

You could replace all the `\n` and `\r` with empty String like this:

```
line = line.replaceAll("\\r?\\n", "")
```

Now you can do the counts and it would not take into account any `\n` or `\r`.

You could alternatively do (Without using regex):

```
line = line.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "")
```

Comment: @jake Show some sample input and output on which it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Hello you should use '\s' in the regular expression that represents white spaces

> \s stands for "whitespace character". Again, which characters this actually includes, depends on the regex flavor. In all flavors discussed in this tutorial, it includes [ \t\r\n\f]. That is: \s matches a space, a tab, a line break, or a form feed.(http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html)

so here how you use it

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(path.toFile(),"UTF-8");
    String content = scanner.useDelimiter("\\A").next();
    System.out.println(content);

    Pattern patternLine = Pattern.compile("\\r?\\n");
    Matcher matcherLine = patternLine.matcher(content);
    int numberLines = 1;
    while (matcherLine.find())
        numberLines++;


    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s");
    Matcher matcherEliminateWhiteSpace = pattern.matcher(content);
    String contentWithoutWhiteSpace=matcherEliminateWhiteSpace.replaceAll("");


    // it will count only ASCII Charachter a->z A->Z 0->9 _'underscore'
    Pattern patternCharachter=Pattern.compile("\\w");
    Matcher matcherCharachterAscii= patternCharachter.matcher(contentWithoutWhiteSpace);


    int numberCharachtersAscii = 0;
    while (matcherCharachterAscii.find())
        numberCharachtersAscii++;
    //it will count UTF-8 charachters it will count all charachter no matter what script it is like français عربي and punctuation
Pattern patternUniversal= Pattern.compile(".");
    Matcher matcherUniversal= patternUniversal.matcher(contentWithoutWhiteSpace);
    int numberUniversalCharachter=0;
    while(matcherUniversal.find())
    numberUniversalCharachter++;
    System.out
            .println("******************************************************");
    System.out.println(contentWithoutWhiteSpace);
    System.out.println(numberLines);
    System.out.println(numberCharachtersAscii);
    System.out.println(numberUniversalCharachter);
```

- **EDIT**

here is a simple modification that will make it work

```
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
          String line = scanner.nextLine();
          lineCount++;
          wordCount += countWords(line);
          charcount += word.replaceAll("\\s", "").length();
          System.out.println(charcount);
          i++;
    }
```

\\s stands for white spaces[tab cariagReturn lineFeed space formFeed ]

Comment: I think this is far to advanced for what I'm working with.

Comment: omit the part of that count  UTF-8  charachters and your are set just delet the petternUniversal and what comes with it and you are done

Comment: tell me what you want and i'll make it simple

Comment: can you please take a look at my corrections to my code. I am close

Comment: OK i will take a look

Comment: yes spaces tabs carriage return or line feed. I can individually right the code to get the lines to print or the chars or the word count I just can't mesh it all together.

Comment: Check it now a have made a modif to your code i have tested it it should work